# Titles for many author papers

Tags: titles, amsbook

I am currently writing a long paper with many (10+) co-authors. We are using the `amsbook` style. (Assume for this question that I want to retain this style.) The current title page lists all authors on a separate line, and is then followed by all of their addresses and affiliations (which are all different). The result is that the title page is two pages long and looks slightly ridiculous. I think I would like to:

1. List several authors per line,
2. Relegate the addresses to the end of the document.

I'm not sure how to do either of these things. Here is a mashup of how the document looks now (Actually, I couldn't include it, as tex.stackexchange.com said that it "looked like spam".)

```
\documentclass{amsbook}

\begin{document} \title{Very Important Theorem}

\author[A. Bloggs]{A Bloggs} \email{abloggs@google.com} \address{Department of Mathematics, Best University Ever, Springfield, USA}

%%% Now take what is above, and make 10+ copies of it. In real life the names and addresses are different, but that is not relevant for observing how it looks.

\begin{abstract} We prove stuff \end{abstract} \maketitle

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome! We'd ask you to post code anyway. We want a minimal working example - a complete but minimal document we can compile to reproduce the problem. (Fake author details, obviously.) Why are you using `amsbook` if you're writing an article? It is not suitable for articles, being designed for books.

Comment: the `amsbook` class was designed to conform to ams specs.  one of the governing specs is that the actual title page for a book published by the ams will be created separately; the title page produced by the package is a "throwaway", needed only to provide the information for the final title page, and to identify the book during the copyediting/production process.  i don't believe that ams has ever published a work (book *or* article) with ten authors; i've certainly never seen one.  i will dig through the code tomorrow to see if i can suggest something.